# play framework 2 work with Request.session value without Action function

Tags: scala, session, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm new to scala and play.

I want call a controller func from view but I don't want to return Result type. 
What I want to do is modify the Request.session value.

The approach I did was : 1) case

1) case

controller :

```
def func(id : Int)(implicit request: RequestHeader) = { ... }
```

routes :

```
GET    /cart/cancel/:id    controllers.ProductController.func(id:Int)
```

But it gave me a compilation error : Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

So I did the another approach 2) case

2) case

controller :

```
def func(id : Int) = Action { implicit request => ... Ok()}
```

Yes. It worked. But this time I have Result type returned.
So I'm obligated to change the state of page anyway

Is there any way to deal with session value without Action function (without state transition) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use case 2 and do something like:

```
Ok().withSession(
  session - "id" + ("id" -> "newID")
)
```

You can then call your controller via Ajax for instance, the change to your session will then be taken into account, you can then apply the changes to UI (if any) once you get the `Ok` status back from your controller. If there are no apparent changes, then you can stop there, all the following interactions with the app will be using this new session.

Comment: How can I do it without returning `Result`? I mean how can I get done with **case 1)** without error?

Comment: You can't, basically, a controller is something that gets a request and returns a response, and this response has to be a valid one. Meaning, the controller has to return either Ok, NotFound... It's the definition of a controller. In Play, you have to define the controller as some sort of Action and this action is passed a function that returns a Result. Bottom line, you can only use case 2.

Comment: Ok, you said it's definition of a controller, I've been searching about what you said but I couln't find any applaudable source claiming that. Could you provide me a source?